# jqGrid with dynamic colModel?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have to create a data table simmiliar to the http://www.chartle.net/ have.

The most importang feature is :

1. Row can be added/remove dynamically (done)
2. Column can be added/remove dynamically (how can i do this ?)
3. The changed colModel  can be saved in database for feature modification ..

Is this possible ?

Comment: I decided to jump on creating lat/long map component on my dashboard first,i'll try to solve this problem next week. Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 5):

Search `getColProp` and `setColProp` in their docs: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods

Comment: jQuery(”#grid_id”).setColProp('colname',{editoptions:{value:“True:False”}});

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that you can't dynamically change the jQgrid ColModel. The two options I see are:

1. Delete the whole grid and reload it with a new ColModel (if it can change entirely) using GridUnload:

   jQuery(selector).GridUnload(selector);
2. Load all possible rows and show/hide the ones you need, e.g. by using the [show hide columns plugin](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:show_hide_columns)

For saving it dynamically it should be sufficient to store the configuration data for the grid in the database as JSON.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible, but haven't tried..

If you use ASP.NET MVC:
Have you tried to programmatically add the grid from the Controller as ViewData?  It's an idea.

This link may get you further : http://arahuman.blogspot.com/2009/06/jqgrid-using-mvc-json-and-datatable.html

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

jqGrid 3.6 now supports dynamically showing / hiding columns, and there is a "Column Chooser" demo on their 3.6 demo page. Is this good enough for your needs?

Answer (score 1):

```
function objedit(id, cellname, value) 
{

    var flag = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        if (obj[i][0] == id && obj[i][1] == cellname) {
            obj[i] = [id, cellname, value]
            flag++;
        }
    }
    if (flag == 0) {
        obj[index] = [id, cellname, value];
        index++;
    }
}


function columnsData(Data) 
{

var formater = "";

    var str = "[";
    for (var i = 0; i < Data.length; i++) {
        if (Data[i] == "Id")
            str = str + "{name:'" + Data[i] + "', index:'" + Data[i] + "', hidden: true,}";
        else
            str = str + "{name:'" + Data[i] + "', index:'" + Data[i] + "', editable: true}";
        if (i != Data.length - 1) {
            str = str + ",";
        }
    }
    str = str + "]";
    return str;
}
//------end grid part----------
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 bindJqGrid("SetPayInvoice", feeID, datasetID, 1);

function bindJqGrid(actionController, feeID, datasetID, step)
 {
    agreementID = $("#agreementID").val();

    mappingTemplateID = $("#mappingTemplateID").val();
    invoiceID = $("#invoiceID").val();
    var action = '/PayInvoice/' + actionController + '?agreementID=' + agreementID + '&mappingTemplateID=' + mappingTemplateID + '&invoiceID=' + invoiceID + '&feeID=' + feeID + '&datasetID=' + datasetID;
    var caption = "Invoice Exception";
    $("#headerText").html(caption);
    JQGrid(caption, action);
}
function JQGrid(caption, action)
 {    $("#tblGrid").jqGrid('GridUnload');

    $.ajax({
        url: action,
        dataType: "json",
        mtype: 'POST',
        success: function (result) {
            if (result) {
                if (!result.Error && result != "" && result != undefined) {
                    $("#TotalData").html(result.records);
                    $("#divWorkflowWrapper").show();
                    $("#dvFooter").show();

                    var colData = "";
                    colData = columnsData(result.column);
                    colData = eval('{' + colData + '}');

                    $("#tblGrid").jqGrid({
                        url: action,
                        datatype: 'json',
                        mtype: 'GET',
                        colNames: result.column,
                        colModel: colData,
                        autowidth: true,
                        height: 550,
                        rowNum: 25,
                        rowList: [25, 50, 75, 100],
                        loadtext: "Loading...",
                        pager: '#tblGridpager',
                        viewrecords: true,
                        gridview: true,
                        altRows: true,
                        cellEdit: true,
                        cellsubmit: "remote",
                        cellurl: '/PayInvoice/GridSavecell',
                        beforeSelectRow: function (rowid) { return false; },
                        ondblClickRow: function (rowid, iRow, iCol) {
                            jQuery("#tblGrid").editCell(iRow, iCol, true);
                        },
                        afterEditCell: function () {
                            e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
                            e.keyCode = $.ui.keyCode.ENTER;
                            edit = $(".edit-cell > *");
                            edit.blur(function () {
                                edit.trigger(e);
                            });
                        },
                       beforeSubmitCell: function (id, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
                            objedit(id, cellname, value);
                            return { id: id, cellname: cellname, value: value, iRow: iRow, iCol: iCol };
                        },
                        afterSaveCell: function (id, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
                            objedit(id, cellname, value);
                            return { id: id, cellname: cellname, value: value, iRow: iRow, iCol: iCol };
                        },
                        caption: caption
                    });
                }
            }
            else {
                $("#divWorkflowWrapper").hide();
                $("#dvFooter").hide();
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            if (xhr && thrownError) {
                alert('Status: ' + xhr.status + ' Error: ' + thrownError);
            }
        }
    });
}
```