# jqGrid: set column property dynamically

Tags: jqgrid

I need to show/hide columns in jqGrid and to filter grid results. 
For hiding and showing I use global array on the page. It keeps state.
For searching and filtering I use build-in filter dialog.
For invisible columns I set property "search" for "false"(nobody wants to sort results if he doesn't see it) so...there is no such column in the filter list. But when I show any column that was hidden(I call $("#jqgrid").showCol(colName);) then this column doesn't appear in the filter list. Of course, I have to change column's "search" property. But how??? Is it possible?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485436/jqgrid-with-dynamic-colmodel/1486345#1486345

Comment: no problem. I love jqgrid too but it seems like sometimes there is so many things in it and no good docs